# routing problem in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I'm new to CodeIgniter and routing.

I have a `Login` controller whose `index()` loads up a view to enter a username/password. In the view, the form has `action="login/authenticate"`. Login->authenticate() determines if the login is valid or not. If it's valid, `redirect('lobby')`, if not `redirect('login')`

routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "login"
```

config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/dts/";
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

The problem is that when i go to `http://localhost/dts/` , click login, I am correctly (?) redirected to `http://localhost/dts/login/authenticate` but the browser says `Object not found!`. But when I go to `http://localhost/dts/index.php/` (with trailing slash), it works correctly (I get redirected to `http://localhost/dts/index.php/login/authenticate`, and am logged in)

I tried removing "index.php" by using a .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

and it would no longer open even the http://localhost/dts/

I'm confused.. what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the last line of your .htaccess file.

Since your application is in a subdirectory ("dts"), the forward slash in front of the "index.php" won't work.  Try removing it so that your file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Follow [**this article on the CodeIgniter wiki**](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/) to properly setup your `.htaccess` as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you change this in your config:

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

To this:

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Also, read this post by Jamie Rumbelow:

http://jamieonsoftware.com/blog/entry/the-best-codeigniter-.htaccess

Thats the .htaccess I've always used and it works great for me.