# Routing in codeigniter php

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, codeigniter

**UPDATE**

If I browse url like

> localhost/myapp/index.php/about_us/index

it works. What is this index.php in url? Do I need to mention it in some config file so that it gets appended and forms correct url in menu/links on site?

**Original Question**

I have no knowledge of PHP but I got a project which in php (codeigniter) to convert in Ruby on Rails.
I could set up db and application well, when I browse application with base url(without mentioning controller & action) it loads page properly. But as soon as I mention url like

> localhost/myapp/home/index

it shows message

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

If I change default controller to anything in routes.php that page with index method works fine but not with explicit mentioning controller and action.

I am not sure what is the issue, I don't know how routing works in php :(

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you dont know php and ur looking for rails routing ????

Comment: What is your web root? `localhost/myapp/`? If so, do you have `home` controller with `index` action?

Comment: @pramodtech both[Rails/codeigniter] are using MVC design pattern so conceptual part is more or less the same

Comment: @Timur web root is localhost/myapp/ and yes I do have home controller with index action

Comment: @swapnesh yes, I understand it and that's why confused on why explicit url doesn't work.

Comment: @pramodtech I am not sure for the codeigniter but just check if it has some config file where you need to set URL routings if any

Comment: What's the server software? Apache? Do you have `mod-rewrite` enabled? Is there a `.htaccess` file on the root?

Comment: @dakdad it's Apache. I have no idea about mod-rewrite, .htaccess is present at root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CodeIgniter, all requests are directed through the `index.php` file, which acts like a [front controller](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/appflow.html).

`index.php` must be present in the URL unless you have created a solution to eliminate it. When using Apache, that is typically done with an `.htaccess` file. There are hundreds of articles and questions regarding this technique -- certainly you can find something to help you.

In regards to URLs and a config option for defining `index.php`, CodeIgniter URL helper functions such as `site_url()` utilize the config setting `$config['index_page']` found in `application/config/config.php`. If you remove index.php from your URLs using an .htaccess solution, you can make this setting blank:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

This setting is useful for when you want to rename index.php to something else, as well (not very common).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you had not configured your web server properly. See this question for details for Apache: [routing problem in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958871/routing-problem-in-codeigniter)

And here are rules for nginx: http://wiki.nginx.org/Codeigniter